# How to prevent imageView expanding by image?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have an imageView which content mode set to .AspectFit. But when I take image from my API and trying to put into it - imageView doesn't transform my image, on the contrary image transforms my imageView and expand it's height size.

I set in constraints height equal to 130, but on the run time it expands to 200.

What is the problem and how can I fix it? I've tried content modes: `AspectFit`, `ScaleToFill`, `Redraw`, `Center` in all cases it expands

Comment: Are you sure the height is actually changing? It might be drawing outside its bounds. Try setting your image view's `clipsToBounds` property to `true`.

Comment: @AaronBrager yes, it works! Thanks! But why it draws outside? =/

Comment: That's how drawing in iOS works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `clipsToBounds` on your image view to `true`.